# Redirect without keeping the url parameters

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

We have a url like this:

```
www.testdomain.com/en-US/Forms/Request-a-Quote.aspx?thankyouid=102&pagename=Get a Quote - LOLIFEX
```

And it has to be redirected to:

```
www.testdomain.com/contact-distributor/
```

No matter what I try or add, it keeps adding the

```
?thankyouid=102&pagename=Get a Quote - LOLIFEX
```

for the `www.testdomain.com/contact-distributor/` so it looks like this `www.testdomain.com/contact-distributor/?thankyouid=102&pagename=Get a Quote - LOLIFEX`

This cause **page not found**, because **WordPress** has the parameter ***pagename*** already set. How can I remove this annoying `?thankyouid=102&pagename=Get a Quote - LOLIFEX` ?

Comment: @anubhava Currently tried like this - source `^/en-US/contact-distributor` destination - `/contact-distributor/`

Comment: @anubhava i use WPEngine redirects, not htaccess file.

Comment: Then why use `.htaccess` tag? Solution would be in documentation of `WPEngine` or in their user forums

Comment: if it is wpengine, I think that you can just add a `?` at the end of the destination

Comment: source = url, Match args = parameters, Destination * = destination+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is WPengine redirects (based on comments)

You can do it like this :

Source * = `/en-US/Forms/Request-a-Quote.aspx?$`

Destination * = `/contact-distributor/?`

Match args = `thankyouid=102&pagename=Get a Quote - LOLIFEX`

Rewrite type * = `permanent`

Which will make the redirect

from `www.testdomain.com/en-US/Forms/Request-a-Quote.aspx?thankyouid=102&pagename=Get a Quote - LOLIFEX`

to `www.testdomain.com/contact-distributor/`

notice the `?`marks

and you can add wildcards etc.

Depending on how many rewrites you need, you could also make a global one, that just takes `/en-US/Forms/Request-a-Quote.aspx/` and sends it to `/contact-distributor/?`

read more about WPengines regex redirects here : https://wpengine.com/support/regex/

PS - WPengine has chat support for this kind a things, which are very helpfull and fast - Just open one of those, if you still have problems.

Comment: you might need to do something about the spaces though

Comment: What if I need to redirect all which starts wiith /en-US/Forms/Request-a-Quote.aspx (thankyouid=102&pagename=Get a Quote - LOLIFEX  - does not depend) ?

Comment: @Lolipopcoder I guess that you would just switch out the match args with `.*` - this should theoretically just accept all parameters that comes after that url? haven't tried it.

Comment: @Lolipopcoder at little like this, but transformed into WPengine : https://regex101.com/r/Z3kcPo/2